# TouchableHighlight inside Viewpager taking page-change event as click in react-native ios

Tags: ios, react-native, touchablehighlight

We have used `view pager` (`react-native-community/react-native-viewpager`) in our app, and there are 3 sections of each and every page , all 3 sections are clickable, for making it clickable we are using `TouchableHighlight`.

So whenever I'm changing my page by swiping. If my touch for sliding is inside `TouchableHighlight` in `IOS` it is taking it as click else in `android` it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this for help for other users like me.

Answer from developer of this library.

**Hey,
you can use onPageScrollStateChanged method, to block button interaction.**

```
switch(pageScrollState){
   case "idle": enableButton();
   default: disableButton(); 
}
```

or I have used this approach.

```
    this.state = {
            shouldEnableClick: true,
        };

    pageScroll = (event) => {
        draggingValue = event.nativeEvent.offset
        isNotStill = (draggingValue == 0 || draggingValue == 1) ? true : false
        {Platform.OS == 'ios' && this.changeValue(isNotStill)}
    }

    changeValue(isNotStill) {
        if (this.state.shouldEnableClick !== isNotStill) {
            this.setState({ shouldEnableClick: isNotStill })
        }
    }
```

and in component I am using it like

```
let enableCLick = this.state.shouldEnableClick
let clickAction = () => this.myAction()

<TouchableHighlight
      onPress={enableCLick && clickAction}/>
```